# Implement Select All on CheckListView JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx

I have a CheckListView which is displaying a list of custom objects. I am trying to implement a select all/ select none option however the list View is not changing. The checkboxes only change if clicked

```
 pendingUsers_listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<User>, javafx.scene.control.ListCell<User>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<User> call(ListView<User> listView) {
            return new PendingUserCell();
        }
    });
```

Custom Cell:

```
public class PendingUserCell extends CheckBoxListCell<User> {

    PendingUserCell() {
        this.setSelectedStateCallback(new Callback<User, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(User param) {

                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(param.isApproved());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(User u, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(u, empty);

        if (empty) {
            this.setText(null);

        } else {

            this.setText(u.getFullName() + " ( " + u.getEmail() + " )");

        }
    }

}
```

These are the functions responsible for the action

```
 public void handleSelectAll() {
       this.pendingUsers_listView.getCheckModel().checkAll();
       this.pendingUsers_listView.refresh();
}

public void handleSelectNone() {
this.pendingUsers_listView.getCheckModel().clearChecks();
this.pendingUsers_listView.refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

I have a `Model` class, that holds the information about the items in the `ListView`, i put there a name, that is displayed in the lisview, and a boolean property that holds the checked/unchecked value like this:

```
 public class Model {

    private StringProperty name;
    private BooleanProperty selected;

    public Model(String name, Boolean selected) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(selected);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

Then I made a custom `StringConverter` to convert Model to String for displaying the text in `listView` like this:

```
public class ModelConverter extends StringConverter<Model> {
    @Override public String toString(Model object) {
        return object.getName();
    }

    @Override public Model fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller I added some items to the `listView` and i put as first element Select All, and a listener for it. So if you check it all items became checked, if you uncheck it you all became unchecked. Here is the code:

```
public class TestController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ObservableList<Model> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private ListView<Model> listView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        listView.setItems(data);
        listView.setCellFactory(factory -> new CustomListCell(Model::selectedProperty, new ModelConverter()));
        data.addAll(new Model("Select All", false), new Model("Apple", false), new Model("Orange", false),
                new Model("Peach", false));
        data.get(0).selectedProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> data.forEach(item -> item.selectedProperty().set(newValue)));
    }

}
```

So I made as simple as it can be, by using one item from the listView, but you can use many ways to select all select none, for example defining two separate `checkboxes` outside of `listView`, or a `togglebutton` or something else that you want, the important is to add a listener to the respective component that you want to use it for select all select none, then everything became easy I think.